# After running the code, I tell the command to my voice assistant, but he does not respond to it, there are no errors

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-3.7

After running the code, I tell the command to my voice assistant, but he does not respond to it and there are no errors.

I tell my bot “what time is it”, but alas, it doesn’t give anything out after that.

I tried to reinstall python

no mistakes, just not responding

I think the problem is in my Python library

```
import datetime
import time
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

opts = {
    "alias": ("Андрей", "Эндрю", "Andrew"),
    "tbr": ("скажи", "расскажи", "покажи", "сколько", "произнеси"),
    "cmds": {
        "time": ("текущее время", "сейчас времени", "который час"),
    }
}

def speak(what):
    print(what)
    speak_engine.say(what)
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()

def callback(recognizer, audio):
    try:
        voice = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
        print("[log] Распознано: " + voice)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("[log] Голос не распознан!")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("[log] Неизвестная ошибка, проверьте интернет!")

        if voice.startswith(opts["alias"]):
            cmd = voice

            for x in opts["alias"]:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            for x in opts["tbr"]:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            # распознаем и выполняем команду
                cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)
                execute_cmd(cmd["cmd"])

def recognize_cmd(cmd):
    RC = {"cmd": "", "percent": 0}
    for c, v in opts["cmds"].items():
        for x in v:
            vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
            if vrt > RC["percent"]:
                RC["cmd"] = c
                RC['percent'] = vrt
    return RC

def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if cmd == "time":
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        speak("Сейчас " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))

r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()

speak("Добрый день, создатель")
speak("Слушаю вас ...")

stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
while True: time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Hello! Why do you think the problem is in your Python library? Also, perhaps add some detail in the question on what this is intended to do?

Comment: in your procedures, (the "def" sections), when you reference `speak_engine` and `sr`, first line in the procedure should be `global speak_engine` and/or `global sr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation's wrong: in the `callback` function, `recognize_cmd` or any other logic that deals with the response will be invoked if and only if `recognizer.recognize_google` raises the `sr.RequestError` exception, so you should move said logic one level of indentation up.

EDIT:

Moreover, due to the usage of `lower()` in `voice = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()`, `voice` will always be *lowercase*, so `voice.startswith(opts["alias"])` will always be false since each element of `opts["alias"]` contains an uppercase character: namely, `А`, `Э` and `A`.

Comment: can you please correct my code as needed because I did like everything you wrote but still does not respond to the words

Comment: @bycyanidee, please see my edit. In general, you should `print(voice)` and see if it passes all the conditions in your code.

Comment: maaan, thx very much, i solved my problem.Сan you tell me something else? How after I found out the time for me to make the assistant continue to perceive my commands

Comment: @bycyanidee, according to [this example](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/background_listening.py), it should be listening until you call the `stop_listening` function... If you want your program to "remember" the last command and use it as a context for further requests, you can create a variable that'll hold this state.